# osm2pgsql Ways importing very slowly in .pbf, much slower than .osm

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm currently importing the planet-latest.osm.pbf file I downloaded from ftp://ftp.spline.de/pub/openstreetmap/pbf/planet-latest.osm.pbf some time last week. I'm importing it using the following command:

```
nohup osm2pgsql -l -U gis -c -v -r pbf --unlogged --drop -s data/planet-latest.osm.pbf &
```

My problem is that the ways are importing very slowly and based on current speed (0.04k/s) and the [OSM stats](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Stats) it will take 86 days to import them all. By contrast the nodes imported at 151.3k/s. Even if I waited 86 days for the ways to import (I won't) I would then need to import the relations and sit through all the post-processing.

I recently imported another planet file in `.osm` format using the same command line arguments and, although it ultimately failed due to [a parsing error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/162513/2788) it was moving along at a *much* faster speed.

From what I can see in the docs I've done everything I can to improve the import speed.

Can anyone tell me why the .pbf format import is moving so much slower over ways than the .osm format?

I'm using PostGIS 9.4 and osm2pgsql 0.88.1. Disks are on a fast SAN, the machine has a single Intel Xeon @ CPU 2.67GHz and 4GB memory. OS is Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

Comment: ways and relations always seem to import more slowly - I assume there is more work. However this speed seems very slow. Did you test with a smaller subset? The only thing I can suggest is that you're not caching nodes (no `--cache` or `-C` option). You don't have much memory, which is bad for planet import, but maybe try `-C 2000`.

Comment: As already mentioned your system doesn't have much RAM. Is it maybe swapping?

Comment: memory is an obvious go-to but it doesn't explain why the .pbf is soooo much slower than the .osm - I'm going to rerun with the .osm today and see what it reports for the speed

Comment: I re-tested with the .osm format file and it's also running slow. Since the last time I imported the .osm I have updated to the latest version of osm2pgsql from a previous 0.82. I found this mailing list entry https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/dev/2011-November/023841.html that suggests dramatic changes in ways import performance at a certain revision. I'm now testing with the --cache option set at 2000 to see if it helps. If now I plan to downgrade osm2pgsql and re-test the pbf

Comment: I'm using osm2pgsql 0.82 on an Ubuntu VPS with 1 core and only 512 MB RAM and I have faster speeds than that.  I set `--cache 200` and it does ok.  This server has SSDs and I have given it considerable SWAP to maintain stability.  Hopefully a downgrade of osm2pgsql helps.

Comment: @tomfumb did you manage to solve this problem, and if yes, how? I have a system with 16 GB ram, and 8 cores, and the importing of ways staggers on with 0.16k/s-0.44k/s. It is driving me mad:((

Comment: @AdamBaranyai I just added an answer with the only approach that worked for me

Comment: On the face of it, this difference from the title between .osm and .pbf shouldn't make sense because https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format says it's "6x faster to read than a gzipped planet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to successfully import was to increase disk space (to 1TB) and use the following command

osm2pgsql -l -U gis -c -r pbf -v -C 30000 --slim --drop --unlogged planet-latest.osm.pbf

Comment: Did this also increase the speed of importing the way entities? My import is still running at the moment, and the ways are being imported with 0.27k/s. When I've posted my queston to the official github forum, they said that those speeds I am experienceing are typical for 7200RPM HDD and 16GB ram. Would you care to explain what are the options do in this command? Isn't -C 30000 presumes that you have at least 30GB ram?

Comment: Which of these options is actually responsible for the speed up? It seems like `-U gis -r pbf -v -c` are just regular options. Is it storing in decimal degrees `-l` that helps, using a cache size of 30G `-C 30000` or the `--unlogged`?

Comment: @barrycarter sorry it's been so long since I've had to run this command that I cannot say

Comment: I tried this myself and `--unlogged` and `-C 30000` helped (`-C 96000` helps even more, if you have the memory). I didn't want to test `-l` because I really do want Mercator coordinates in my db.

Answer (score 2):

I try to
vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

```
shared_buffer=4GB
work_men=521M
maintenance_work_mem = 4GB
checkpoint_segment=20
autovacuum=off
effective_cache=16GB
```

The node speed is 1.3k

Comment: You should add some detail to the question. I assume, but should write it, that you think/know that the problem is with the configuration of PostgreSQL, and the above config should resolve it?

Comment: This comment got downvoted but it's a step in the right direction. One of the bottleneck for importing is postgress and you should switch off fsync and autovacuum while importing to help you speed up the postgress.

Comment: From PostgreSQL 9.5 on, the parameter `checkpoint_segments` is replaced with `min_wal_size` and `max_wal_size`. More on this [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/release-9-5.html). This other [StackExchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168464/postgresql-9-6-best-settings-for-large-admin-work-min-wal-and-max-wal#183868) could also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have a computer,the machine has a single Intel Xeon @ CPU 2.39GHz(16cpus) and 64GB memory. OS is Ubuntu 14.04 Server. but I  use the following command:

```
osm2pgsql -a -s -C 4096 --number-processes 16  -S vector-datasource/osm2pgsql.style -j europe/south-america-latest.osm.pbf  -d osm -H localhost
```

osm2pgsql version 0.91.0-dev (64 bit id space)

Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Using projection SRS 3857 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=4096MB, maxblocks=65536*65536, allocation method=11
Mid: pgsql, scale=100 cache=4096
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels

Reading in file: europe/south-america-latest.osm.pbf
Using PBF parser.
Processing: Node(1220k 1.3k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)

The speed is 1.3

Comment: vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf      shared_buffer=4GB
work_men=521M
maintenance_work_mem = 4GB
checkpoint_segment=20
autovacuum=off
effective_cache=16GB

Comment: I'm getting 70.5k/s for nodes, and was getting over 100k/s when I did `-C 96000` (though it really slowed the machine down). Maybe I should stop complaining :)